# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3dc9.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, directx, directx-9

I'm currently going though a game programming book and am trying to compile some directx9 code

I have the latests DirectX11 SDK and the code has these lines of code

```
#pragma comment(lib,"d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"d3dx9.lib")
```

But I get 
     LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3dc9.lib'

I don't know how to set it up to find this file although in fact I don't get why it asks for it since it isn't inside the Lib file for the DirectX 11 SDK and isn't what i've asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker only knows the name of the .lib file, it doesn't know what directory it is stored in.  Project + Properties, Linker, General, Additional Library Directories setting.

The version 11 SDK is quite new.  You may need an older version of the SDK if these .libs are no longer distributed.  I know the June 2010 edition has them.  Download [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6812).

Comment: I've downloaded the June 2010 edition but it turns out it's what I had anyway. I can't physically find the d3dc9.lib file is the SDK folder. Where should it be? It's not at C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86

Comment: You're right, I don't have a d3dc9.lib file there either, only d3d9.lib and d3dx9.lib.  I went by your snippet, not your question title.  No real idea what "dc" might mean or where it comes from.  Are you mis-typing the name?

Comment: No, it really is complaining about d3dc9.lib and that really doesn't exist, can't find any reference to it in my own code that i'm trying to compile, i've tried searching the entire project for any reference to it and can't find it.

Comment: Well, there are two distinct google hits for "d3dc9.lib", you're the top one.  Both with my name on it, depressing.  Solved the 2nd hit but I'll have to throw in the towel on this one.

Comment: Thats was really silly of me, I had an external dependacy and had made a typo there. I started a fresh project, just added the code to the main and then it worked without messing with the settings at all.